# NgIf not triggered on value-change in Subject Subscription

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, subject

The NgIf is not triggered when the value is changed in a Subject scubrsciption.
The console prints the correct wanted values for **responseState**.
The **responseStateSubject** is given through input by other components.
*I already had it implemented with NgOnChanges, but that was too much out of my hands for me.*

Component code:

```
   @Input() responseStateSubject: Subject<RequestResponseState>;
        
   ngOnInit(): void {
             
    
   this.responseStateSubject.subscribe((x) => {
        //****  This is the relevant part, it does set the  property and prints the corresponding value. *//
    
                this.responseState = x as RequestResponseState;
                console.log(this.responseState);
    
        //****//
                if (x != undefined && x != null) {
                  this.mainWrapper.nativeElement.classList.add("open-main-wrapper");
                  if (x.requestEnum != this.requestResultBaseEnum.Loading) {
                    this.utilsS.scrollElementIntoView("response-main-wrapper");
                  }
                } else {
                  if (this.mainWrapper != null) {
                    this.mainWrapper.nativeElement.classList.remove(
                      "open-main-wrapper"
                    );
                  }
                }
              });
    }
```

Component html:

```
<div #mainWrapper id="response-main-wrapper" class="flex-center">
  <div
    *ngIf="responseState != null && responseState != undefined"
    id="message-main-container"
  >
    <hr class="grey-hr" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What change detection strategy do you use in the component?

Answer (score 0):

using **ChangeDetectorRef**'s **detectChanges()** method solved it for me.

Comment: Instead of calling detectChanges() you should subscribe to the subject in html using the async pipe and do the other stuff in a tap in pipe. Otherwise you risk memory leak by not unsubscribing the observable.

Comment: @ThomasRenger, i am unsubscribing to the subscription in the NgOnDestroy hook. Should be fine aswell, right?